# rails gives wrong session cookie to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, session, cookies

We are using omniauth with facebook login in a Rails 3.2.13 app. It has pretty standard boilerplate code in the sessions_controller to manage user sessions.  It uses the CookieStore for sessions.  Here is the sessions_controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_authorization_check

  def new
    redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
  end


  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.where(:provider => auth['provider'], 
                      :uid => auth['uid'].to_s).first || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
# Reset the session after successful login, per
# 2.8 Session Fixation – Countermeasures:
# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation-countermeasures
    reset_session
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    user.add_role :admin if User.count == 1 # make the first user an admin
    if user.email.blank?
      redirect_to edit_user_path(user), :alert => "Please enter your email address."
    else
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Signed in!'
    end

  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Signed out!'
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => "Authentication error: #{params[:message].humanize}"
  end

end
```

The other day a member of our team was testing our production version and went to go sign in to the app.  When she browsed to the app she found she was already signed in as another user who had never used that computer or in fact ever been in our building.  Based on what she experienced and our subsequent analysis it seems that she was given a session cookie for that user by the app.  After much research I don't understand how that could happen i.e. the rack/rails framework could give a session cookie to the wrong user.  Has anyone seen this before or heard of it happening?  Any suggestions on how to debug this or where to put logging to get more insight into what could be going wrong?

Comment: session store?
Passenger?
memcache?

Comment: Not sure if you are asking if we are using any of those things or suggesting that we switch to them?  But we are using Thin.  CookieStore for storing session info. We've deployed on Heroku and are not using memcache at the moment.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: No never did.  We switched to using Devise shortly after I asked this question and haven't seen the problem since.  Not sure if it was the switch or it is just hard to reproduce.